# Can't load data using Ajax for Razor Pages

Tags: ajax, razor-pages

I have this ajax call in my view, Form.cshtml

```
<form id="myForm">    
<input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Load data" />
<p id="result"></p>
</form>
@section scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
            debugger
            $.get('/Form/',function (data) {
            debugger
            console.log('test');                
        });
        })

    });
</script>
}
```

and in my Razor Pages code behind, Form.cshtml.cs

```
    public class FormModel : PageModel
{
    public JsonResult OnPost()
    {
        List<Student> students = new List<Student>{
            new Student { Id = 1, Name = "John"},
            new Student { Id = 2, Name = "Mike"}
        };

        return new JsonResult(students);
    }
}
```

The problem is it doesn't reach OnPost method. If I put in OnGet, it will automatically load **before** I click the Submit button.

I try to create another Razor page called Filter.cshtml and in Filter.cshtml.cs. And then in my Form.cshtml, I changed my url to `/Filter/`, it did reach OnGet in Filter.cshtml.cs

```
    public class FilterModel : PageModel
{

    public JsonResult OnGet()
    {
        List<Student> students = new List<Student>{
            new Student { Id = 1, Name = "John"},
            new Student { Id = 2, Name = "Mike"}
        };

        return new JsonResult(students);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use the jQuery `post` method, not `get`: `$.post('/Form/',function (data)...`

Comment: I tried with post but still didn't reach OnPost

Comment: @Steve check ive modified answer

Answer (score 1):

The default behaviour of clicking a submit button in a form is that the form gets submitted. At the moment, your form has no `method` specified, so the submission will default to the `GET` method. If you want to submit the form by AJAX `POST` rather than the usual behaviour, you need to do two things:

1. Cancel the default action of the button click (which is what currently causes the `OnGet` handler to execute)
2. Change the jQuery code to use the `POST` method:

```
@section scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function (e) { // include the event parameter
            e.preventDefault(); // prevents the default submission of the form
            $.post('/Form/',function (data) { // change from 'get' to 'post'
                console.log('test');                
            });
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the $.get() makes Ajax requests using the HTTP **GET** method, whereas the $.post() makes Ajax requests using the HTTP **POST** method.

```js
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json",
  url: "/Filter/OnGet",
  success: function (result) { 
   }
 });
```

Comment: Actually, the purpose of my trying out another page is to test. But, I need to do it in same Razor page, Form.cshtml.